# Adding a message to a product in the cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I am looking for a way of displaying custom message to certain products in the cart depending on the product attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do it using **Event/Observer**.

Fire create ***an observer*** on the event `checkout_cart_product_add_after`.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));
```

**Observer**

```
<?php
class {Namespace}_{ModuleName}_Model_Observer
{
    public static function showCustomMessag(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        # Get event
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $quote_item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();

        if($product->getData({Custom_Attribute_Code})== {Yourvalue}){                
            $this->getCheckoutSession()->addError(
                    Mage::helper('checkout')->__('{Your_messgae}')
                );


        }

        # Do stuff
    }
    public function getCheckoutSession()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it ok?...Jurģis Toms Liepiņš

Comment: like same how can i work with the selected category, eg: if the selected category of products added to cart display like "Thank you", how can i do this for 3 category, i know the id of a category?